# Testing with Grunt, Mocha, Require.js and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to setup this configuration, but I need help. I'm trying to use: https://github.com/accordionpeas/grunt-mocha-require-phantom.

My structure:

```
build-dev/            <-- Generated by grunt
    vendor/
        js/
            jquery.js
            require.js
 js/
    model/
        cache.js         <-- File to be tested
    tests/
        cache.js        <-- Test for a file
        tests.js             <-- like test-bootstrap.js
```

My gruntfile config is:

```
mocha_require_phantom:
    devel:
        options:
            base: 'build-dev/js'
            main: 'tests'
            requireLib: '../vendor/js/require.js'
            files: ['tests/**/*.js']
            port: 3001
```

My tests.js (test-bootstrap.js) is:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../vendor/js/jquery',
        chai: '/node_modules/chai/chai'
    },
    baseUrl: '/'
});

mocha.setup({
    ui: 'bdd'
});

require([testPathname], function() {
    if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
     return mochaPhantomJS.run();
    } else {
        return mocha.run();
    }
});
```

My tests/cache.js is:

```
define(['chai', 'model/cache'], function(chai, cache) {
    var should;
    should = chai.should();
    return describe('test suite 1', function() {
        return it('should work', function() {
            return cache.test().should.be.equal(5);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is it's not working. It can't load model/cache.    I was trying to change baseUrl in tests.js (like test-bootstrap.js). I was also trying to change baseUrl in grunt. I was trying to add path: `model: ../../js/model`, but it was ignored.

I need to call for a model as `model/cache`, how do I have to set up things to make it work? Should I use another plugin - which one?

Edit: Fixed typos.